# Inserting Arrays into SQL Junction Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016

The background is I'm getting device data from an API which has nested objects and multiple arrays such as IPAddress could have multiple addresses. The goal is put this into a SQL 2016 database normalized. If possible, I'm trying to avoid reformatting the data too much with for loops and am trying to avoid cursors for performance reason.  It would be ideal to pass a string that is delimited and have SQL do the heavy lifting.  In this example, there are two tables, the first for devices

1. tblDevices - for this example this going to contain each device and static settings, for simplicity just a device name
2. tblJuncIpAddress - this table has an IP associated with the device and type of 1 or 2

I tried to use this example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4884/sql-server-2016-stringsplit-function/

Can I do update\insert code with JOIN or CROSS APPLY that would add\update a device and add\update an IP address?  I was trying something like this but CROSS APPLY wasn't liking the format.

```
DECLARE @DeviceName varchar(50) = 'Server123'
DECLARE @IPAddressType1 varchar(250) = '1.2.3.4,1.1.1.1'
DECLARE @IPAddressType2 varchar(250) = '8.8.8.8,9.9.9.9'

INSERT INTO tblFSDevices ('deviceId') Values (@DeviceName)

DECLARE @devId int = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO tblJuncIpAddress (devId, ipAddress, [type])
SELECT Id, SPL.value, 1
FROM tblDevices
WHERE devId = @devId
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@IPAddressType1,',') AS SPL;
```

If it matters, the code getting the API data and inserting is Powershell.  I've seen other examples where you are generating the ('IP1'),('IP2') and then doing an INSERT on those values in bulk, but I'm not sure how you implement a UPDATE or INSERT unless you are just doing a DELETE first to remove existing records.  I'm open to any solution, the goal is to get the one > many values into the database as simple as possible.

Comment: You have the where clause before the CROSS APPLY. Switch those around and this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to store your IPs as a comma separated string, a more straightforward solution might be do the multiple inserts like this:

```
INSERT
INTO tblJuncIpAddress (devId, ipAddress, [type])
VALUES (@devId, @ip1, 1), (@devId, @ip2, 1), (@devId, @ip3, 1)
```

If you must store the IPs as a comma separated string, you should be able to do an insert like this:

```
INSERT
INTO tblJuncIpAddress (devId, ipAddress, [type])
SELECT @devId, Value, 1
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IPAddressType1,',')
```

Based on what I am seeing, there should be no need to use `CROSS APPLY`.